# Приведение типов (погорел)

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Разбираюсь с кодом:

```
Set<Integer> nominals = nominalsAndCount.keySet();
Integer[] a = nominals.toArray();
```

`toArray()` должен возвращать не только `Object`, но и `T[]`
но он возвращает только `Object`
как мне вернуть интаджир без поломки разработки и танцев с бубном в цикле переопределяя тайп?

Comment: brainfuck - это метка для конкретного языка

Answer (score 10):

Эта проблема связана с т.н. Type Erasure. Типы в дженериках существуют только в момент компиляции, когда вы создаете `ArrayList<Integer>`, информация об Integer будет использована только на этапе компиляции, а в рантайме на самом деле будет создан `ArrayList<Object>`. Из-за этого и появляется проблема: чтобы рантайм смог корректно проинициализировать массив, ему нужен тип, а он этот тип сам по себе не знает (и даже не может использовать хаки с взятием первого элемента и т.п. - внутри массива могут быть объекты со сложной иерархией классов, и непонятно, какой из этих типов брать). Поэтому пустой `toArray()` всегда возвращает `Object[]`.

Однако, кроме `toArray()` без аргументов существует еще и `T[] toArray(T[] array)`. Вызов этого метода как раз даст вам то, что требуется (потому что вы таким образом передаете рантайму конкретный тип): массив элементов нужного типа. У этого метода немного [запутанное поведение](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/), в общем случае рекомендуется вызывать его с пустым массивом длиной в ноль элементов:

```
Integer[] result = collection.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```