# Java. Нужна помощь в создании своей обертки на массив

Tags: java, массивы, generics

Мне дали задание написать свою обертку на массив. Но столкнулся с проблемой работы дженерика. Дело в том, что мне надо иметь динамическую структуру, и я хотел к примеру добавление написать так:

```
public class SimpleArray<E> extends ArrayIterator<E> implements Simple<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(E o) {
        // values это массив значений от итератора унаследован.
        values = new E[values.length + 1]; // проблема!
        ...
    }
```

У меня проблема, что я не могу создать объект типа `new E[]`, а увеличивать размер как-то надо. Но, задание само по себе на дженерики и мне надо работать именно с неопределенными типами... Помогите пожалуйста. Какие тут выходы? Как мне создавать массив с длинной большей чем есть?

Comment: Вы делаете массив или итератор?

Comment: Храните в `Object[]` и кастуйте при операциях возврата, ArrayList так и делает. Там всё [довольно сложно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555378/16095) и другие решения будут не очень производительными.

Comment: >>>Вы делаете массив или итератор?<<< Я делаю свою обертку чтобы  использовать массив как динамическую структуру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было предложено @etki, расширять массив нужно созданием `Object[]`:

```
public class SimpleArray<E> extends ArrayIterator<E> implements Simple<E> {

    E[] values;

    @Override
    public boolean add(E o) {
        // values это массив значений от итератора унаследован.
        values = (E[])new Object[values.length + 1];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16 если я правильно понимаю, это class cast exception, я поэтому и акцентировал на возврате отдельных элементов.

Comment: Я бы не стал публиковать пример без проверки. ClassCastException не будет

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17833216/2908793 я, в общем, не совсем спец по этим делам, но ArrayList оперирует над Object[], и, кроме того, в саму структуру массива записывается его тип (в данном случае - Object), поэтому оперируя с ним, как c E[], остается только надеяться, что его никто не проверит.

Comment: Мне известна реализация ArrayList. Предложил альтернативу